# Is likert type scale interval or ordinal?

Tags: measurement

In educational research, some researchers say likert type scale is interval scale and some others say it is ordinal scale. which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is subject to interpretation and is often disagreed in a general context. From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale),

> Whether individual Likert items can be considered as interval-level data, or whether they should be treated as ordered-categorical data is the subject of considerable disagreement in the literature,[10][11] with strong convictions on what are the most applicable methods. This disagreement can be traced back, in many respects, to the extent to which Likert items are interpreted as being ordinal data.

Likert scales don't actually assign values to options by definition but are assigned arbitrarily by the researchers conducting the survey. As such I would consider it an ordinal scale, unless the context implied a natural numerical interpretation - but this is not a hard rule by any means.